# Is there a better way to directly convert a Rust BSON document to JSON?

Tags: json, mongodb, rust, serde

The idea is getting a cursor from Mongo and serializing the result set to JSON in a string. I have working code:

```
extern crate bson;
extern crate mongodb;

use mongodb::db::ThreadedDatabase;
use mongodb::{Client, ThreadedClient};

extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;

fn main() {
    let client =
        Client::connect("localhost", 27017).expect("Failed to initialize standalone client.");

    let coll = client.db("foo").collection("bar");

    let cursor = coll.find(None, None).ok().expect("Failed to execute find.");

    let docs: Vec<_> = cursor.map(|doc| doc.unwrap()).collect();

    let serialized = serde_json::to_string(&docs).unwrap();

    println!("{}", serialized);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? If not I will close this thread.

Comment: https://docs.rs/bson/0.13.0/bson/ I let you do the "rest" of the search.

Comment: I believe that asking for ways to *improve your code* are [better suited for Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of situation that [`serde-transcode`](https://crates.io/crates/serde-transcode) was made for. What it does is it converts directly between `serde` formats. How it works is it takes in a `Deserializer` and a `Serializer`, then directly calls the corresponding serialize function for each deserialized item. Conceptually this is a bit similar to using `serde_json::Value` as an intermediate format, but it may include some extra type information if available in the input format.

**Unfortunatly, the `bson` crate does not expose `bson::de::raw::Deserializer` or `bson::ser::raw::Serializer` so this is not currently possible.** If you look in the documentation, the `Deserializer` and `Serializer` actually refer to different structs which handle the conversion to and from the `Bson` enum.

If `bson::de::raw::Deserializer` was public, then this code would have the desired effect. Hopefully this will be helpful to anyone who has a similar problem (or anyone who wants this enough to raise an issue on their [repository](https://github.com/mongodb/bson-rust)).

```rust
let mut buffer = Vec::new();

// Manually add array separators because the proper way requires going through
// DeserializeSeed and that is a whole other topic.
buffer.push(b'[');

while cursor.advance().await? {
    let bytes = cursor.current().as_bytes();

    // Create deserializer and serializer
    let deserializer = bson::de::raw::Deserializer::new(bytes, false);
    let serializer = serde_json::Serializer::new(&mut buffer);
    
    // Transcode between formats
    serde_transcode::transcode(deserializer, serializer).unwrap();

    // Manually add array separator
    buffer.push(b',');
}

// Remove trailing comma and add closing bracket
if buffer.len() > 1 {
    buffer.pop();
}
buffer.push(']');

// Do something with the result
println!("{}", String::from_utf8(buffer).unwrap())
```